# Setting MySQL "lower_case_table_name" server variable

Tags: mysql

Running MYSQL 5.1 on windows 7. . . how do I change the server variable for 'lower_case_table_names'.  Need to set it to 0.  I've tried to set it from the command prompt using mysqld.exe, and I've tried manually changing the my.ini file. . . no luck.

Does anyone have some sure-fire/straight-forward do-this, and then this instructions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. . . couldn't change the variable w/ mysql workbench running. Closed it out, restarted the service and the changes took effect. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this will only affect new tables, existing tables will not be affected by this property.

Comment: thats fine. . .  I can delete the existing db, and re-dump. . . my problem is when I run 'show variables' / 'lower_case_table_names' is still set to 1.